# Use cURL to add a JSON web page's data in Solr

Tags: json, curl, solr

I see from the [UpdateJSON](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON) page how to use a command prompt to index a standalone file stored locally. Using this example I was able to successfully make a .json file accessible through Solr:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true' --data-binary @books.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```

What I'm not able to find is the proper syntax to do the same for a webpage containing JSON data. I've tried with the @:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true' --data-binary @[URL] -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```

and without:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true' --data-binary [URL] -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```

Both ways lead to errors. How do I configure a command to prompt Solr to index the contents at [URL]?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, (https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ContentStream) you should first ensure remote streaming is enabled (solrconfig, search for enableRemoteStreaming)

Then the command should be of the kind:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true&stream.url=YOURURL' -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```